# Batch script is always asking to overwrite file in the morning

Tags: batch-file

I have a task scheduled in Task Scheduler to run an AutoExec in Access and export a txt file (Lapco_PO.txt).  Then I have another task scheduled to run a batch file, during the day it runs smoothly or when I manually run them.  However, every morning I come in my cmd prompt is up asking to overwrite the file and it is saying it can't find the files to move/rename.  This is my batch file that runs after the file is exported.  I am not sure why it is not being able to find the files.

```
xcopy "M:\Sage 100 Advanced\2018\MAS90\John\MAS_Mirror\Lapco_PO.txt" "O:\Purchase Orders\z-POs\Automated_PO\2021\Lapco_PO"
del "M:\Sage 100 Advanced\2018\MAS90\John\MAS_Mirror\Lapco_PO.txt"
set HR=%time:~0,2%
set HR=%Hr: =0% 
set HR=%HR: =%
rename "O:\Purchase Orders\z-POs\Automated_PO\2021\Lapco_PO\Lapco_PO.txt" "PO_%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%_%HR%%time:~3,2%.txt"
xcopy "O:\Purchase Orders\z-POs\Automated_PO\2021\Lapco_PO\*.txt" "O:\Purchase Orders\z-POs\Automated_PO\2021\Lapco_Sent"
```

This is the cmd screen;

```
C:\Users\jarett.AS\Documents>xcopy "M:\Sage 100 Advanced\2018\MAS90\John\MAS_Mirror\Lapco_PO.txt" "O:\Purchase Orders\z-POs\Automated_PO\2021\Lapco_PO"
File not found - Lapco_PO.txt
0 File(s) copied
C:\Users\jarett.AS\Documents>del "M:\Sage 100 Advanced\2018\MAS90\John\MAS_Mirror\Lapco_PO.txt"
Could Not Find M:\Sage 100 Advanced\2018\MAS90\John\MAS_Mirror\Lapco_PO.txt
C:\Users\jarett.AS\Documents>set HR=18
C:\Users\jarett.AS\Documents>set HR=18
C:\Users\jarett.AS\Documents>set HR=18
C:\Users\jarett.AS\Documents>rename "O:\Purchase Orders\z-POs\Automated_PO\2021\Lapco_PO\Lapco_PO.txt" "PO_2021-06-15_1808.txt"
The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\Users\jarett.AS\Documents>xcopy "O:\Purchase Orders\z-POs\Automated_PO\2021\Lapco_PO\*.txt" "O:\Purchase Orders\z-POs\Automated_PO\2021\Lapco_Sent"
Overwrite O:\Purchase Orders\z-POs\Automated_PO\2021\Lapco_Sent\PO_2021-06-15_1808.txt (Yes/No/All)?
```

Comment: Are you sure that `M:` and `O:` are referring to a different location? :-)

Comment: You'd use the `/Y` option of `xcopy.exe` to supress the prompt for overwrite. Please open a Command Prompt window, type `xcopy /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read its usage information. Also if `M:` and/or `O:` are network locations, then the scheduled task can only be run as a user who has those mapped, and they would need to be logged in when it is run!

Comment: @Dominique yes they are two different network locations

Comment: @Compo Since M: and O: are network locations, I have the condition "Wake the computer to run this task" checked off.  If the task can only be run if I am logged in how does the cmd prompt pop up?

Comment: I didn't mean that the task can only be run if you're logged in, I meant that the mapped network drives will not be available/accessible whilst you're not logged in! The script will still run, as it is configured to do so, its just that it cannot perform all of the functions during that not logged in state. Your persistent drive mapping is performed at login.

Comment: @Compo ok I understand, I am going to adjust the TS to only run during business hours and see if I have any issues, thanks

Comment: To be able to work "when not logged in", your script should connect to the network drives ( `net use /?`) before trying to work on them. They will disconnect when the script ends.